# How to deploy ASP.NET application with MS SQL server database

Tags: web-development

I want to deploy my website with MS SQL server database.  It's my first time and I have never done it before.

What I have come to know from my googling is that I must have a domain(.com/.net/.co) and a host(for my web pages `.aspx` & `.cs`(**confusion here if I can also deploy my database**)).

Now, I am not getting to where I have to deploy my database.  If I also have to buy a seperate SQL Server database or a host consisting of every thing (means I can deploy both my ASP.NET application & database as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need the do following:

1. Find a hosting company that provides .net and MS SQL, which many windows hosting companies do
2. Create the database on your host using the panel that they provide
3. The panel should provide you with a connection string for the new database
4. Replace your current connection string with the one for the new remote database or use different web.config files, like web.local.config and web.live.config
5. Upload your website using VS or FTP
6. Open both your local database and the remote database (on your host) in VS and copy the table definitions - open the table definition of a local table select every row, copy, then paste the rows in a new table definition on the remote database
7. You can also copy all of the contents of the tables in the same manner

Then see if it worked.